# how to retrieve the time from the TimeSelector in the gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, gridview, time

i have a gridview and inside i have a TimeSelector, but how am i going to retrieve the time from the gridview cause if normally it is a TextBox we will use this

```
Dim rbSelect As TextBox = DirectCast(GridView2.Cells(1).FindControl("TextBox"), TextBox)
```

so how should i retrieve the time from the timeselector in the gridview?

time picker control:
    <%@ Register Assembly="TimePicker" Namespace="MKB.TimePicker" TagPrefix="cc1" %>

```
<ItemTemplate>
<table style="width: 79%; height: 31px;">

<tr>
 <td class="style1">
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Time to start:"></asp:Label>
</td>
 <td>
  <cc1:TimeSelector ID="TimeSelector3"  runat="server" AllowSecondEditing="false" DisplaySeconds="False" Height="25px" MinuteIncrement="15" Width="150px" />
 </td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td>
  <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" 
                                    onclick="Button1_Click" />
</td>
  </tr>

 </table>
</ItemTemplate>
 <ControlStyle Width="100px" />
<ItemStyle Width="210px" />
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is some information for you how to do this:

1. Add reference to the TimePicker.dll. See more information about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). The picker I just was [this](http://www.asp.net/community/control-gallery/Item.aspx?i=3221)
2. On the aspx page that you are working at the to you write. To see more information about how to formulate the register tag see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c76dd5k1%28vs.71%29.aspx):
   `<%@ Register Assembly="TimePicker" Namespace="MKB.TimePicker" TagPrefix="mkb"%>`
3. To use the `TimePicker` aka `TimeSelector` (I know this because I looked at the dll in .net reflector see [this](http://www.reflector.net/)). You need to have one `ScriptManager` per page.
    `<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>`
4. To use the control on the page write:
    `<mkb:TimeSelector ID="TimeSelector1" runat="server"></mkb:TimeSelector>`

This is how you add a single `TimeSelector` to you page.

Here is a full example of a `TimeSelector` inside of a gridview:

**Default.aspx**

```
<%@ Register Assembly="TimePicker" Namespace="MKB.TimePicker" TagPrefix="mkb"%>
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false"
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:GridView ID="gvTest" runat="server">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <mkb:TimeSelector ID="TimeSelector1" runat="server"></mkb:TimeSelector>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    </form>
</body>
```

**Default.aspx.vb**

```
Public Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim ls As New List(Of String)()
        ls.Add("Test")
        ls.Add("Test2")
        gvTest.DataSource = ls
        gvTest.DataBind()
    End Sub

    Private Sub gvTest_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvTest.RowDataBound
        If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
            Dim picker As MKB.TimePicker.TimeSelector = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("TimeSelector1"), MKB.TimePicker.TimeSelector)
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub Save()
        For Each row As GridViewRow In gvTest.Rows
            Dim picker As MKB.TimePicker.TimeSelector = DirectCast(row.FindControl("TimeSelector1"), MKB.TimePicker.TimeSelector)
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: but the problem is when i type TimePicker,it have underline, so what the problem?

Comment: Have you include the namespace?

Comment: still cannot this is how i register for the assembly
<%@ Register Assembly="TimePicker" Namespace="MKB.TimePicker" TagPrefix="cc1" %>

Comment: when i mouse over it , it ask me to Generate 'Class Time Picker' or Generate new type

Comment: Have you added the Timepicker as a refrence to you project?

Comment: add in, but still got underline

Comment: Updated the answer for you hope this helps

Comment: thanks it work i change to MKB.TimePicker.TimeSelector it work